# vim restore point?

Tags: vim

Can we set a restore point and restore a file's state while editing the file with VIM?... 
I saw the *"earlier"* and *"later"* commands. But what if i dont remember the exact time to go back. So I want to know if there is a way to set restore points (and name them if possible) and restore the file using the restore point? Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this, but there's a superb plugin available [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1997) that allows you to do `:UTMark tagName` to mark the current state in the undo tree and use `:UTMark tagName` to restore that state.

Overall, using a source control system is much better for general long term history, but this can be useful for navigating small changes.

Comment: This is what I was looking for... Thanx

Comment: +1 Nice. Seems there's a vim plugin for everything :-).

Answer (score 2):

No, not that I'm aware of.

But you could just write (:w file) your file to a new name (e.g.with date+time appended). This will keep the original filename in your buffer (so :w, :x will continue to work normally).

If you write the temp files to a temp directory, the OS can clean them up automatically. For bonus points, make that into a small vim macro, so you can invoke it with one key.

Comment: or you could use source control.

Comment: I have a source control system.. I wanted to revert state in one editing session... small changes...  Thanx..